# How to make setup.py install multiple top-level packages?

Tags: python, build, installation, setuptools, distutils

I have a python package that I would like to organize like so:

```
root/
    setup.py
    package1/
        __init__.py
        package2/
            __init__.py
        package3/
            __init__.py
```

I would like `setup.py` to install `package1`, `package2`, and `package3` into the correct `site-packages/` directory as top level packages, so that I could execute

```
import package1
import package2
import package3
```

without a problem.  Perhaps this needs multiple `setup.py` files?

But most importantly, I'd like to ultimately be able to install all three packages by executing `pip install root`.  How do I do this?  Preferably a `distutils`-only solution, though setuptools is ok as well.

Comment: In your example file tree, do you mean to have package2 and package3 inside package1, or did you want them all to be at the same level?  If the other two are inside package1, then installing package1 will install them.  If you then install them on their own, they'd be installed twice.

Comment: For the file tree, package2 and package3 are inside package1.  But when they get installed, I went all the packages to be top level.  That is, I'd like to be able to import package2 from the python shell, rather than import package1.package2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel it is cleaner to have your development file/folder structure more closely represent the deployment structure.

What this means is, I'd place all three packages at the same level instead of nesting them.

If you subsequently want to be able to import all three via one of them, you can set up a dependency in your single setup.py file.

Answer (score 9):

You can try

```
packages=['package1', 'package2', 'package3'],
package_dir={
    'package2': 'package1',
    'package3': 'package1',
},
```

to tell distutils that packages 2 and 3 are located inside package1.

A full working setup.py could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='root',
      version='1.0',
      description='Root package',
      author='Me',
      author_email='me@example.org',
      url='https://example.org/root',
      packages=['package1', 'package2', 'package3'],
      package_dir={
          'package2': 'package1',
          'package3': 'package1',
      },
)
```

`python -m pip install ./root` installs the packages into the structure you look for, such that

```
import package1
import package2
import package3
```

work.

As a proof, this is how `ls package*` looks like in the site-packages dir:

```
package1:
__init__.py __pycache__

package2:
__init__.py __pycache__

package3:
__init__.py __pycache__
```

And this is the `root-1.0.dist-info/RECORD` file:

```
package1/__init__.py,sha256=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU,0
package1/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc,,
package2/__init__.py,sha256=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU,0
package2/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc,,
package3/__init__.py,sha256=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU,0
package3/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc,,
root-1.0.dist-info/INSTALLER,sha256=zuuue4knoyJ-UwPPXg8fezS7VCrXJQrAP7zeNuwvFQg,4
root-1.0.dist-info/METADATA,sha256=Z1crlNNrRhJwO6O2ujtNsCo9rURrPoZGE0--ZhuBZsU,190
root-1.0.dist-info/RECORD,,
root-1.0.dist-info/WHEEL,sha256=g4nMs7d-Xl9-xC9XovUrsDHGXt-FT0E17Yqo92DEfvY,92
root-1.0.dist-info/top_level.txt,sha256=svjaZCiNfClr21KxGb71MTR7bWON1-VZRPiPgM0FjV4,27
```